# If for every $x_n$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$, there exists a $x_{n_k}$ such that $Tx_{n_k} = Tx$, is $T$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T$ be the (possibly nonlinear) map $T\colon X \rightarrow Y$. $T$ is continuous if for every $x_n \in X$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$, then $Tx_n \rightarrow Tx$. Is $T$ also continuous if instead, for every $x_n \in X$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$, then there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $Tx_{n_k} = Tx$?

Comment: Yes. This follows from the fact that if   $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ and $(Tx_n)$ does not converge to $Tx$, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $\Vert Tx_{n_k}-Tx\Vert>\epsilon$ for all $k$. That this fact holds follows from the definition of convergence.

Comment: @DavidMitra, that one subsequence is bounded away from $Tx$ does not exclude that another subsequence could approach $Tx$.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong Yes. But *no* subsequence of $(Tx_{n_k})$ could converge to $Tx$.

Comment: Ah, right, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood the question first. Indeed the answer is yes. If $Tx_n$ does not go to $Tx$ one can choose subsequence $x_{n_k}$ that is bounded away from $Tx,$ e.g. $\|Tx_{n_k}-Tx\|\ge\varepsilon.$ This leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry for posting what has been posted in the comments...

Comment: I you feel uncomfortable doing so, you have the possibility of making the answer community wiki.